# FB Like Button not working properly, counts multiple posts at one

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

My problem is that I was using a "Like button" plugin on wordpress and I didn't liked the looks of it. I deactivated the plugin and then tried with manual code of XFBML button. That screwed the count to some of the posts, having their counts all in one. I reverted the changes, using the plugin again, deleted the code added and the problem persists. Some of the posts have the "shared" count box. And when you "Like!" any of that posts, only the last one appears on Facebook.

It's it possible that this is a caché issue or something that is wrong in the code?

I tried reverting the meta tag "og:type" from "blog" to "website" but it didn't allowed me, can this be the problem?

Why do some of  the posts share that countbox if the links are not the same?
And the wierdest thing, why only some of the posts have the issue while some are shared correctly?

As for an example, say post 1, 5 and 7 share the same countbox (+200). When you "like!" any of them, only the last of them (the most recent) gets to the FB wall.
This doesn't happen with the new posts, only with part of the old ones.

If the case, you can see it working: http://elrincondelacritica.com/

Thanks in advance.

By the way, if you need any piece of code just ask, this is not my page and I really need to fix this asap, also because it's online and running.
Thank you.

Comment: Liking external Objects uses the object URL as identifier – so make sure that a), each of your posts is available under it’s own URL, and b), that you set the href parameter for each like box to the URL of that specific post you want it to like.

Comment: So, I use something like this now ..href=<?php urlencode(the_permalink()); ?>.

Does changes have any long delay or facebook registers almost instantly?

Comment: Use the FB debug tool to clear its cache: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks mate for the share. Next time I make a website I'll make sure to create an APP too.

And by the way, the error was because of the meta tag `og:type` changed from `website` to `article`. What I did was to leave it to `article` (not trying to change it "forcing" `og:type` - `website`) and placing each "bad" post in the FB Debugger. There were 30 or so... but it worked, and now the new posts work too, with zero count from the start and incrementing correctly, each in particular.

Answer (score 0):

The FB debug tool shows that you didn't supply the fb:app_id > which seems to be crucial to render the news feed.
See: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Felrincondelacritica.com%2F

You can create a Facebook App here: http://developers.facebook.com/apps
Once you've done that you can add the fb:app_id by adding this into your header:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="000yourAPID000"/>
```

Comment: Hmm... I really doubt that creating and using an app in facebook will resolve this.There are millions of blogs and worpdress blogs out there, hundreds of thousands using mere "Like!" button without any problem or having to create the app.

Comment: By the way, I modified the "slug" name of a "damaged" post, just to test it out, and facebook recognised it in the right manner. I think it my have something to do with the cache of facebook.

Comment: This article explains why the use of a FB app is advised:
http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-social-plugins-to-wordpress-posts/
It says "To make your WordPress website or blog an “object” in Facebook’s Open Graph, you first need to get an App ID for your site or blog."
So it might solve your problem. Why not try it? It takes about a minute to set up a FB app